# How to make org chart created using HTML and CSS responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have created an organization chart using HTML and CSS. It looks fine on my desktop, but in responsive my connectors get all messed up. How can I make my code work in responsive? Below is what I have. It looks messed up in the snippet code as well.
Problem: .level-2wrapper::before should be on the right of .level-2::before

```css
:root {
  --level-1: #8dccad;
  --level-2: #f5cc7f;
  --level-3: #7b9fe0;
  --level-4: #f27c8d;
  --black: black;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

ol {
  list-style: none;
}



.orgchart {
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}


/* LEVEL-1 STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.level-1 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  background: var(--level-1);
}




/* LEVEL-2 STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.level-2-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.level-2-wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: 182px;
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(97.5%);
  background: var(--black);
}
.level-2-wrapper li + li {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.level-2 {
  font-weight: normal;
      background: #026fc2;
    color: #fff; 
}
.level-2::before {
      content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 112%;
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: var(--black);
}

.oc{
display: flex;
    }



/* LEVEL-2 STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.level-sub-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.level-sub-wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 27%;
  background: var(--black);
}
.level-sub-wrapper li + li {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.level-sub {
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #026fc2;
    color: #fff; 
}
.level-sub::before {
      content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: var(--black);
}


 .level-sub-wrapper::after {
   content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 88px;
    left: 80px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 2px;
    height: 20px;
    background: var(--black);
  }

.level-sub2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #026fc2;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="orgchart">
<h1 class="level-1 rectangle">CEO</h1>

<div class="oc">
<ol class="level-2-wrapper">
<li>
<h2 class="level-2 rectangle">Person A</h2>
</li>

<li>
<h2 class="level-2 rectangle">Person B</h2>
</li>

<li>
<h2 class="level-2 rectangle">Person C</h2>
</li>

<li>
<h2 class="level-2 rectangle">Person D</h2>
</li>
</ol>

<ol class="level-2-wrapper">
<li>
<h2 class="level-2 rectangle">Person E</h2>
</li>

<li>
<h2 class="level-2 rectangle">Person F</h2>
</li>

<li>
<h2 class="level-2 rectangle">Person G</h2>
</li>

<li>
<h2 class="level-2 rectangle">Person H</h2>
</li>
</ol>

<ol class="level-sub-wrapper">
<li>
<h2 class="level-sub rectangle">Person E</h2>
</li>

<li>
<h2 class="level-sub2 rectangle" style=" margin-left: 20px;">Person F</h2>
</li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Start by NOT using `position: absolute;`